# Why doesn't deleting "negative" answers give an achievement?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, achievements-dialog

I started doing some cleanup and deleted some pretty old answers of mine with a negative score.

Shouldn't I see a bunch of +2s showing up in achievements?

Comment: Do you see a *removed* event in your *reputation* tab? I recently deleted an old question after it reached negative score, but since the positive reputation from upvotes was higher than the negative reputation from downvotes, [it resulted in a net reputation loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDjAM.png) and it didn't appear in the achievements dropdown.

Comment: I do recall that I saw something like that when I deleted answers some time last year. Looking at my reputation tab for today, it only shows activity around content I wrote today.

Comment: Maybe the same rule applies at it does to gained reputation - that deletions after 30 (or 60, don't remember) days will not affect reputation?

Comment: @Pekka웃 [No](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345873/deleting-negative-answers-doesnt-give-an-achievement#comment458969_345873)

Comment: @Servy ahh, indeed

Comment: Don't forget [this achievement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure) :-)

Comment: @Bergi collected that one long time ago. Nowadays I see my mission in helping others to achieve that badge :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're referring to the achievements dialog in the top bar, no. We don't show post removed events in that dialog. You'll only be able to see those events in your reputation history, and only if you have the box next to "show removed posts" at the bottom of your history checked. All of the +2 events from those deletions *do* show up there as expected.

[image: +2 removed]

Comment: Is there difference for "pretty old posts"? I remember you don't lose rep for removal of 60+ days old posts (or something along this lines) - I'd expect no gains either...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If the post is 60 days old and has a score of 3+, the reputation isn't reversed.